# Dynamic Allocation on Hive on Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I configured spark engine in hive-site.xml using:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
I configured spark engine in hive-site.xml using:
<property>
  <name>hive.execution.engine</name>
  <value>spark</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>spark.master</name>
  <value>yarn-cluster</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>spark.executor.cores</name>
  <value>4</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors</name>
  <value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors</name>
  <value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors</name>
  <value>8</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>spark.shuffle.service.enabled</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>spark.executor.memory</name>
  <value>3g</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>spark.driver.memory</name>
  <value>3g</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>spark.serializer</name>
  <value>org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>spark.io.compression.codec</name>
  <value>lzf</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>spark.yarn.jar</name>
  <value>hdfs://VCluster1/user/spark/share/lib/spark-assembly-1.3.1-hadoop2.7.1.jar</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>spark.kryo.referenceTracking</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>spark.kryo.classesToRegister</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveKey,org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable,org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorizedRowBatch</value>
</property>
In yarn-site.xml:
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
  <value>mapreduce_shuffle,spark_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.spark_shuffle.class</name>
  <value>org.apache.spark.network.yarn.YarnShuffleService</value>
</property>
```

When I run hive on spark job, dynamic allocation is not working. Spark would automatically assign spark.executor.instances to whatever the number I set to spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors and not change. Can anyone help me to figure out the problem?

Thanks

Comment: what version of hive you are using ?

Comment: @ArunakiranNulu I am using hive-1.2.1. Spark version 1.3.1